# Get elements from object and compare with Array - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, loops

```
var words = [
    {word: 'cow', explain: 'animal'},
    {word: 'apple', explain: 'fruit'},
    {word: 'dog', explain: 'animal'}];
var word2 = ["cow", "dog"];
```

How do i compare *words* with *word2* and color the matching words *red* with Jquery?

My issue lies in the object, i cannot extract the elements in *word*

Can you help me? 
Thank you

Comment: You can't color anything with javascript

Comment: if some html markup is implied - you should post it. Otherwise, there's nothing *to color*

Comment: You want to get the index of `word2` in `words`?

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question, you can use `Array.filter()`:

```
var words = [
    {word: 'cow', explain: 'animal'},
    {word: 'apple', explain: 'fruit'},
    {word: 'dog', explain: 'animal'}
];
var word2 = ["cow", "dog"];

var wordsInWord2 = words.filter(function (obj) {
    return word2.indexOf(obj.word) !== -1;
});
```

Assuming your Javascript is running in a web browser, the second part of your question would require HTML, since Javascript doesn't really have a way of directly outputting colored text.

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
words.filter( function(e,i,arr){
  return word2.filter(e2 => e.word === e2).length; // only keep the words form word2
}).forEach( function(e,i,arr){
  /*do something where e is of the form {word: ..., explain: ...} */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var words = [
    {word: 'cow', explain: 'animal'},
    {word: 'apple', explain: 'fruit'},
    {word: 'dog', explain: 'animal'}];
var word2 = ["cow", "dog"];

var result = [];
words.forEach(function(e){
    if(word2.indexOf(e.word) != -1)
        result.push(e);
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

it is fairly simple... but you need to convert words into an object first

```
var words = {
  "cow": { "explain": "animal" },
  "apple": { "explain": "fruit" },
  "dog": { "explain": "animal" }
};
```

and then

```
for (var i = 0; i < words2.length; i++)
{
    if (words[words2[i]])
    {
        // found a math at index i
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to do it with Jquery? or is it the most optimal way to do so with javascript for loop?

Comment: jQuery is based on js... you may use js for abstract logic rather then jQuery. as you can see from the other answers you can also search your array with the *filter* method but beware.. you won't be able to extract the index of the result

Comment: @FrederikPeterVolkers You have a misconception about JQuery.  JQuery works on DOM objects found in HTML (ie html tags), but have given us plain old Javascript objects which is not the same thing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies - help me out alot - thx!